# Перенос значения из input в textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Все доброго времени!
Необходимо при заполнении формы на одной странице перенести все ее значения в одно поле textarea

```html
<form role="form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="number">Номер счета</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Например, №00006959">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Название товара</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title"
                   placeholder="Например, скрипт агрегации платежей UNIPAY">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sum">Итоговая стоимость, руб.</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sum" placeholder="Только цифры, например, 1200">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect w-md waves-light m-b-5">Сгенерировать
                ссылку
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="textArea">Платежная ссылка</label>
            <textarea id="textArea" class="form-control" rows="5"><?php echo base_url();?>pay/form/?</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</form>
<!-- end row -->
```

Благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: т.е. надо все значения сложить как текст и потом всё это дело сложть с текстом в textarea???

Comment: Да, все верно! Все значения должны быть в строке textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function foo(){
  var x= document.getElementsByTagName("input");
   document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = "";
  for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML += x[i].value + "/";
  }
}
```

```html
<form role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="number">Номер счета</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Например, №00006959">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Название товара</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Например, скрипт агрегации платежей UNIPAY">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sum">Итоговая стоимость, руб.</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sum" placeholder="Только цифры, например, 1200">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect w-md waves-light m-b-5" onclick="foo();">Сгенерировать ссылку
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textArea">Платежная ссылка</label>
        <textarea id="textArea" class="form-control" rows="5">
          </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
<!-- end row -->
```

Comment: Хотел бы добавить замечание к данному ответу, что для точной работы будет также уместно добавить функцию очистки textarea при нажатии на кнопку "Сгенерировать ссылку".

Comment: все правельно, уже добавил...

Comment: спасибо! все работает!